# Laravel : how to validate a form field according to possible values of a Model's attribute?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm performing validation of a form, where a user may select a range of values (based on a set of entries in a model)

E.g. I have the Model CfgLocale(id, name)

I would like to have something like:

CfgLocale->listofAvailableIds() : return a array

What I did is:

Inside Model this method:

```
class CfgLocale extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cfg_locales';



    public static function availableid()
    {
        $id_list = [];
        $res = self::select('id')->get();
        foreach($res as $i){
            $id_list[] = $i->id;
        }

        return $id_list;
    }
}
```

On Controller for validation I would do then:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'id'                => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ...
    'locale'  => 'required|in:'.implode(',', CfgLocale::availableid()),
]);
```

Any better Idea, or Laravel standard to have this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [exists rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists) of laravel.You can define a validation rule as below. Might be this can help.

```
'locale' => 'exists:cfg_locales,id'
```

Comment: this is what I was missing. Thanks. Anyway I think it could have been more stylish and solid if we could refer to the model instead of the table name....

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead,

```
class CfgLocale extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cfg_locales';

    public static function availableid()
    {
        return $this->pluck('id')->toArray();
    }
}
```

`pluck` method selects the `id` column from your table and `toArray` method converts your model `object collection` into `array`.

Know more about `Laravel Collections` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections).

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array of IDs:

```
public static function availableid()
{
    return $this->pluck('id')->toArray();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-toarray